# Colon in batch variable name

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-processing

I have a batch script which should have access to a variable named something like `env:dev`, so it has a colon inside... this variable is set by a third-party component, so I don't have influence on that naming...

How can I access the content of this variable in my batch script? I know that `:` is a special character, so can I perhaps escape it? The following doesn't work:

```
echo %env:dev%
echo "%env:dev%"
echo %env^:dev%
...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `:` colon has special meaning in `CMD` environment variables if command extensions are enabled (Windows `cmd` default), for instance

- [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html):

  - `%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%`
- [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html):

  - `%variable:~num_chars_to_skip%`
  - `%variable:~num_chars_to_skip,num_chars_to_keep%`

Hard to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) a `:` colon in variable name, ***if possible*** at all. Here's a workaround: create variables with such names that `:` colon is replaced by another character, e.g. `_` *Low Line* (underscore):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem create sample variables
set "env:dev1=some thing!"     value contains exclamation mark
set "env:dev2=some thing%%"    value contains percent sign
set "an:other=some:thing3"     another name containing colon 

echo --- before ---
set env
set an

for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%G in ('set') do (
    set "auxName=%%G"
    set "auxValue=%%H"
    call :colons
)

echo --- after  ---
set env
set an

rem 
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:colons
  if not "%auxName::=_%" == "%auxName%" set "%auxName::=_%=%auxValue%"
goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
==> d:\bat\so\37973141.bat
--- before ---
env:dev1=some thing!
env:dev2=some thing%
an:other=some:thing3
--- after  ---
env:dev1=some thing!
env:dev2=some thing%
env_dev1=some thing!
env_dev2=some thing%
an:other=some:thing3
an_other=some:thing3

==>
```

**Edit**: for the sake of completeness:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem create sample variables
set "env:dev1=some thing!"     value contains exclamation mark
set "env:dev2=some thing%%"    value contains percent sign
set "an:other=some:thing3"     another name containing colon

rem use sample variables 
SETLOCAL DisableExtensions
echo Disabled Extensions %env:dev1% / %env:dev2% / %an:other%
ENDLOCAL
```

Be aware of disabling command extensions impact, read `cmd /?`:

> The command extensions involve changes and/or additions to the
>   following commands:
>
> ```
> DEL or ERASE
> COLOR
> CD or CHDIR
> MD or MKDIR
> PROMPT
> PUSHD
> POPD
> SET
> SETLOCAL
> ENDLOCAL
> IF
> FOR
> CALL
> SHIFT
> GOTO
> START (also includes changes to external command invocation)
> ASSOC
> FTYPE
> ```
>
> To get specific details, type commandname /? to view the specifics.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Oh man, how can one put `:` in a variable name... what a mess.